# Progressbar with Percentage Text in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, progress-bar, portable-class-library

I am trying to build an app using Xamarin forms PCL project in which I need to show a progress bar with filled % text next to it like this-

[image]

I have tried box view but I am having difficulty in setting its width as per my percentage.

I have tried progress bar as well-

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <ProgressBar BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Progress="0.08"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20"/>
            <Label Text="25"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
```

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both the `ProgressBar` and `Label` in a `Grid` container. A grid container lays out multiple elements on top of each other. Next set the `Margin` left of the label relative to the percentage of the progress bar. You may have to fiddle with the exact margin to get it to align properly.

Example:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0">
    <ProgressBar BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Progress="0.08"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20"/>
    <Label Text="25" Margin="80,0,0,0"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If i have a stack layout with horizontal orientation then on appending labels in it, last trailing label are cut by its width is there any property like linebreakmode for stacklayout so that elements which are not fit enough comes to next line.

Comment: Thanks! for the solution.

Comment: Is it possible to have an icon over progress bar? Based on the progress value, need to move the icon front or back. I have no idea about the position part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Absolute layout or relative layout in this case with 2 children progressbar & label and based on progress change the text property.

Comment: I am using Acr.UserDialogs nuget
var _dialog = Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Loading();

Comment: MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BaseViewModel, double>(this, "BaseViewModel", (sender, _percentageMessageAlert) =>
            {
                     _downloadDataProgress.IsVisible = true;
                    _dialog.Title = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(_percentageMessageAlert * 100)).ToString() + "%";                    
     _downloadDataProgress.CustomProgress = _percentageMessageAlert;
            });